# Error finding path for dockerfile of golang

Tags: docker, go, dockerfile

im trying to build docker image with my golang project

I use the following

```
#build stage
FROM golang:alpine as builder
WORKDIR /go/src/app
COPY . .
RUN CGO_ENABLED=0 GOOS=linux go build -a -installsuffix cgo -ldflags '-extldflags "-static"' -o main .
RUN apk add --no-cache git


#final stage
FROM alpine:latest
RUN apk --no-cache add ca-certificates
COPY --from=builder /go/bin/app /app
ENTRYPOINT ./app
LABEL Name=fzr-dbc  Version=0.0.1
EXPOSE 3000
```

This build is failing in my `main.go` file which is looks like following

```
package main

import (
    "fzr-dbc/cmd/tsr”
)

func main() {
    tsr.Execute()
}
```

when I run the command
`docker build -t fzr .`
**The error is:**

```
main.go:4:2: cannot find package "fzr-dbc/cmd/tsr” in any of:
        /go/src/app/vendor/fzr-dbc/cmd/tsr (vendor tree)
        /usr/local/go/src/fzr-dbc/cmd/tsr (from $GOROOT)
        /go/src/fzr-dbc/cmd/tsrs (from $GOPATH)
```

The error since it’s not finding my project path , what could be missing here ?

The docker file is in my root project `fzr` and I run the docker build from there

Comment: What's missing is, quite literally, your Go package called 'fzr-dbc/cmd/tsr'.  Where is this code installed?

Comment: @Flimzy - the docker file is in my root project, `fzr` and I run the build from there

Comment: @Flimzy - this is not solving this ? `COPY . . ` which copy my project to the container ? of course if I run it from the root project

Answer (score 0):

You are running `go build` in your Dockerfile:

```
RUN CGO_ENABLED=0 GOOS=linux go build -a -installsuffix cgo -ldflags '-extldflags "-static"' -o main .
```

This requires you to install all your dependencies for building it.

To fix this, either:

1. Build the binary on your host and `COPY` the binary directly into the docker; or,
2. Install dependencies inside your docker as part of `RUN` processes:

   - For Go before 1.11, you need to move your project source code into proper directory in `GOPATH`. Then, on that folder, run `go get -u ./...`
   - For Go 1.11+, you need to use Go 1.11 with `go.mod` and `go.sum` properly defined. Then you can use the command `go mod download` to download all the dependencies to the Go package cache inside your docker image.